# javascript confirm() not working in mobile/responsive design

Tags: javascript, firefox, cross-browser

I'm making a cross-browser web application using PHP and javascript. But the javascript method `confirm` is not working when I use it in my phone's mozilla firefox browser and in mozilla firefox's responsive design mode. by 'not working' I mean nothing happens when the button is clicked.

but the code works fine in google chrome's responsive design tester extension. is there any solution to this?

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    confirm("Press a button!");
}
</script>
```

Comment: It might not be supporting confirm box in that case you would use some javascript based plugins

Comment: is it really necessary to use a plugin for such a basic javascript function? I wonder why no one has ever had a problem with this before..

Comment: I also encountered this issue, it's weird it does not work on responsive mode, but it works on an actual mobile device Firefox.